# Best solution (library) for working with scanner device in java?

Tags: java, twain

I am working at a desktop project (develop with swing) which works with wide range of old and new scanner devices.
We want an open source and free library that can work with scanner devices. Scanner standards like Twain , ... are not important for us, supporting wide range of scanner under Windows (XP and 7) is very important for us.
Please share your experience about this subject with me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Well I think TWAIN should be very important to you, because it *is* the data acquisition standard. Virtually all scanners come with TWAIN drivers giving you a standard interface. So what you really need is a Java TWAIN library. Unfortunately, there is no good open source library.

Out of commercial offerings consider: [JTwain](http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/) and [Morena](http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp.html). I think Morena has a "Personal Licence", which is free, but not suitable for a commercial project.

You can also try these JARs from [here](http://code.google.com/p/openbizcard/source/browse/trunk/integrated/Scanner/src/com/yov/lib/?r=103). They were developed by someone on the net whose site is now dead, but you can reverse engineer it with JAD quite easily to get the API list.

Comment: Actually used Morena and is very good

Comment: The JARs mentioned were in the openbizcard project on Google Code.  That project has been migrated to github numerous times, one of which is [here](https://github.com/deeiip/openbizcard/tree/master/integrated/Scanner/src/com/yov/scanner/lib).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about open source, but you use to be able to get a "personal" license for [Morena 6](http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp.html) which was free.

Comment: So, this was post at the same time as one other answer, and before another, yet it’s the only one to attract a down vote, how curious

Answer (score 1):

You really want TWAIN support. Coding to a device specific API is not very reusable.  If you are looking for a free solution and are familiar with JNI then I wrote an article with the most basic solution and free source code for Java and C++.  The article is [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074455/java-app-dev/bridge-the-gap-between-java-and-twain.html).  If you are looking for a low cost solution then you may try [JTwain](http://www.jtwain.com)

Comment: the link to the jtwain website is now dead.

Comment: The current url to JTwain is: http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/index.php

Comment: Asprise apparently has it available through an AGPL-3.0 license [on github](https://github.com/Asprise/java-scanner-access-twain).